# Why there is not a consistent pattern between the carbon chain length and the melting point of fatty acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, melting-point, fats

I looked at the melting temperature of different saturated fatty acids and I expected to see that with a longer chain of carbon the melting point would be higher as after all the var der Waals interactions would be stronger, yet I found there is not a consistent pattern between the number of carbons in the carbon chain and the melting point:

C3H6O2: Melting point: −20.5 °C

C4H8O2: Melting point: −5.1 °C

C5H10O2: Melting point: −34.5 °C

C6H12O2: Melting point: −3.4 °C

C7H14O2: Melting point: −7.5 °C

C8H16O2: Melting point: 16.7 °C

C9H18O2: Melting point: 12.5 °C

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: You could have added acetic acid $\ce{C2H4O2}$, melting point +$16.6$°C.  This strange behavior must be related to the crystallographic structure of these acids in the solid state.

Comment: And why you neglect hydrogen bonding? It doesn't simply add to other interactions, but interferes.

Comment: Based on the formulas, those are *saturated* fatty acids, not unsaturated

Comment: @Andrew You are correct